# difference between actions-on-google lbrary vs action on google vs dialogflow library

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am working on Dialogflow using the library action on google https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google for fulfillment. I am confused because there are articles on actions on google, which appears to be related to google assistance integration. Is action on google different than actions-on-google, there is also something call actionsdk.

Should I even be using actions-on-google for dialogflow development?

Answer (score 1):

There are three potential libraries you may want to use, each of which has specific purposes.

- [`actions-on-google`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) - The library for building fulfillment for Actions on Google using Dialogflow as the underlying NLP source.
- [`dialogflow-fulfillment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment) - The library for building fulfillment for Dialogflow when integrated with any service, such is the Dialogflow web embed. This library does not include features specific to Actions on Google like media playback.
- [`@assistant/conversation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@assistant/conversation) - This library is for building fulfillment for Actions on Google using the new Actions Builder or new Actions SDK tools.

In your case, you are already using Dialogflow and you are building an Action. For you, the best library to use is `actions-on-google`.